# Why is AVPlayerViewControllerAnimationCoordinator generating an undeclared type error?

Tags: avplayerviewcontroller

Why is AVPlayerViewControllerAnimationCoordinator generating an undeclared type error? As far as I can tell the method below is just a delegate method of AVPlayerViewController.

And yes I did import AVKit. Auto Complete wouldn't work on the method but I pasted it in directly from the docs.

```
extension SWVideoPlayerVC: AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {

    override func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willTransitionToVisibilityOfTransportBar visible: Bool, with coordinator: AVPlayerViewControllerAnimationCoordinator) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s only available on tvOS 11+ [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontrollerdelegate/2876484-playerviewcontroller)